# KineticJS - how to save the canvas to an image

Tags: kineticjs

I have updated a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipens/69hh4/6/)

Note, in the fiddle, the images are hosted elsewhere.
However, when running locally - the images are hosted on the same server as the script is executing.

All I am trying to do is let the user click the "Save" link.
When this happens, I am expecting the following code to kick in and replace the image that sits underneath the canvas:

```
    stage.toDataURL({
    callback: function(dataUrl) {       
        $d('#saved').attr("src",dataUrl);
    }});
```

Can anybody see what I have done wrong?
I can't even alert out the dataUrl - which means the callback function isn't being executed.

Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Because I didn't have more of your code, I just replaced $d with $('#saved').attr("src",dataUrl);   Are you sure you're not getting CORS security errors?

Comment: +1 My guess is that you're trying to get the data url of an image that's not hosted on your domain name.  Can you please tell us if you're seeing a JavaScript error?

Comment: Yes, it is strange - it is working fine now. Thanks for looking in to it.